# Node.js not deploying on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, express-handlebars

I've got a Node.JS+express app running using express-hbs. Everything works when running locally, but fails when deploying to Heroku.

I have tried some of the obvious troubleshooting steps such as:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 80;
```

But the issue still persists.

Here is the full error:

```
/app/node_modules/express-hbs/lib/hbs.js:90
   var matches = str.match(layoutPattern);
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
     at ExpressHbs.declaredLayoutFile (/app/node_modules/express-hbs/lib/hbs.js:90:21)
     at parseLayout (/app/node_modules/express-hbs/lib/hbs.js:476:27)
     at /app/node_modules/express-hbs/lib/hbs.js:598:7
     at getSourceTemplate (/app/node_modules/express-hbs/lib/hbs.js:572:16)
     at compileFile (/app/node_modules/express-hbs/lib/hbs.js:594:5)
     at /app/node_modules/express-hbs/lib/hbs.js:647:16
     at ReaddirpReadable.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/express-hbs/lib/hbs.js:196:17)
     at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
     at ReaddirpReadable.emit (events.js:208:7)
     at endReadableNT (/app/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:1010:12)
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 1
```

Locally I am running Node.js v6.11.4 and NPM v3.10.10, both of which are included in package.json

Answer (score 0):

This may be an [issue](https://npm.community/t/npm-err-cannot-read-property-match-of-undefined/234) with you `package-lock.json` file getting out of sorts... Especially, since the error is originating from within your `express-hbs` node module:

> app/node_modules/express-hbs/lib/hbs.js:90

Maybe you could try *deleting your local `package-lock.json` file, as well as your `node_modules`* directory, and then try reinstalling your dependent libraries?

For example, once your `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` have been deleted:

```
rm package-lock.json
rm -rf node_modules
```

Try *reinstalling your project's dependent `npm` libraries* with an: `npm install`

Once these libraries have been reinstalled, you will have a fresh up-to-date `package-lock.json` file, since this **file is autogenerated** and serves almost like the "*source of truth*" for the building of your project to others. Now try *pushing and publishing* your code to `Heroku` and see if this resolves your issue.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include my node/npm versions in my initial post, made an edit. My version doesn't seem to produce a package-lock.json. I have also made a npm shrinkwrap file which seems to act like a package-lock.json but that has had no effect on Heroku